# Understanding section headers ELF

Tags: c, elf

```
static inline Elf32_Shdr *elf_sheader(Elf32_Ehdr *hdr) {
    return (Elf32_Shdr *)((int)hdr + hdr->e_shoff);
}

static inline Elf32_Shdr *elf_section(Elf32_Ehdr *hdr, int idx) {
    return &elf_sheader(hdr)[idx];
}
```

Okay the first function here returns a pointer to a elf section header by using `hdr_shoff` because that is the offset to first section header . Now the second function is used to access more section headers ( if there be any ) just by using array indexing .

```
static inline char *elf_str_table(Elf32_Ehdr *hdr) {
    if(hdr->e_shstrndx == SHN_UNDEF) return NULL;
    return (char *)hdr + elf_section(hdr, hdr->e_shstrndx)->sh_offset;
}

static inline char *elf_lookup_string(Elf32_Ehdr *hdr, int offset) {
    char *strtab = elf_str_table(hdr);
    if(strtab == NULL) return NULL;
    return strtab + offset;
}
```

I am having problems with the above two function used for accessing section names . `e->shstrndx` is the index of the string table . So in `elf_str_table` we first check it against `SHN_UNDEF` . But in the `return` I don't understand that `hdr->e_shstrndx` is the index to a string table , how is that index added to the starting address of the elf_section header giving another elf section header ( as we are using it access `sh_offset` ) . My confusion is that `e->shstrndx` is an index to a string table but how is it that this index along with `elf_section` returning a pointer to `struct Elf32_Shdr`  ?

Reference : http://wiki.osdev.org/ELF_Tutorial#Accessing_Section_Headers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said yourself that `elf_section` returns a section header based on an index.

`e_shstrndx` is the index of the section header that contains the offset of the section header string table.

So, you use `e_shstrndx` as a parameter for `elf_section` to get that section header :

```
Elf32_Shdr* shstr = elf_section(hdr, hdr->e_shstrndx);
```

Then get the offset from that section header :

```
int strtab_offset = shstr->sh_offset;
```

And use it to get the actual string table :

```
char* strtab = (char*) hdr + strtab_offset;
```

From this string table, you can then get the names of sections based on their offset :

```
char* str = strtab + offset;
```

Comment: oh I understand it now , string table is also a section which has it's own section header which is given by the offset `e_shstrndx` , am I right ?

Comment: @AbKDs : that's the gist of it, yes.

Comment: Thanks @Sander De Dycker . There you go with your upvote and accept :)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I'm having some trouble understanding the *sh_offset* field. If *e_shstrndx* is pointing to the string table with the section name, why do we need to use *sh_offset*?

Comment: @Trey : `e_shstrndx` is the index of a specific "section header" (within the "section header table"). This section header contains (among other things) the byte offset within the file (`sh_offset`) of the "section name string table". Or in other words : section headers don't contain the actual section - they just contain where to find the section.